# Can't set production server to production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

On my production server I have set environment variable by adding the following to `/etc/environment` :

```
 ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

I checked it has recorded with `printenv ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` after a reboot.

My server is Ubuntu 14.04 and I am using asp.net core 1.1.

It is loading my `appsettings.Development.json` instead of `appsettings.Production.json`.

This is my startup.cs contructor

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Inside my log file I can correctly see it says `Hosting environment: Production` but if I output values from configuration file to view then it is values from contents of `appsettings.Development.json`.

I even tried deleting `appsettings.Development.json` from server and rebooting entire server but it still pulls the same values I guess it must be compiled somewhere.

I have also tried adding this to .csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My settings files appear nested inside VS2017 like this:

[image]

The default appsettings.json just has a defualt value for logging, it doesn't contain the values I am pulling.

I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @Set nothing referring to environment in web.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly a long shot, but you may have fallen into the same trap that I did. You need to explicitly include environment-based `appsettings.*.json` files during the publish process. They were not included by default for me, though I haven't checked the latest project templates to see if that's still true. If you haven't checked whether the `appsettings.Production.json` file is physically present on your production server, it might be worth a look.

If it turns out that this is your problem and you're still using `project.json` then if yours looked like mine used to, you'll need to add something like this:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.*.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
```

With the `"appsettings.*.json"` entry being the important one.

If you've upgraded to `csproj` then [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj) may help you work out what you'll need in the new project file format.

Comment: I am using csproj.  I haven't added them explicitly but they are copied to the publish directory.  The strange thing is even if I delete `appsettings.Development.json` my views still output the values inside `appsettings.Development.json` even though it no longer exists (even with a reboot).  I guess it is being compiled somewhere.  I tried adding ` <None Include="appsettings.*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />` to csproj itemgroup but it didn't change anyhting, it still takes development values.

Comment: @Guerrilla What's in your base `appsettings.json`, if you have one?

Comment: I have one, linked picture in OP.  It just holds a defualt value for logging.  I have added all my settings to development & production files.

Comment: @Guerrilla Everything *looks* right to me, and if you're seeing `Hosting environment: Production` I'm at a bit of a loss. The fact that deleting the development version of the settings continues to use those settings after a reboot seems significant to me. Have you checked the contents of the `appsettings.Production.json` file on the server to ensure they're correct?

Comment: It turned out to be a combination of things.  Cache keeping old message, kestrel not properly restarting without full reboot and a bug in my code.  Thank you for your help, you were entirely right, problem lay elsewhere all along.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Double check the value that `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` has when you start your application. For example, if you see `Hosting environment: Development` in starting logs then the value is not setup for this process.

Note that `export` set variable `ONLY` for current shell and all processes started from current shell. For permanent setup you need to modify `.bashrc`.

Comment: I have added it to /etc/environment so it is permanent and I have confirmed with reboot.  In the log files it says "Hosting environment: Production" so I guess there must be some other reason it is loading the wrong json file?